# TextBlock doesn't update content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, binding

I have a TextBlock where I want to write text into. To do this I use a TextBox and some other logic in the background.

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding Chunk}"  
    TextBlock.FontFamily="Arial" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding Chunk, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Width="400" 
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    MaxHeight="80" 
    Margin="0,10,20,10" 
    Padding="0,5,0,5" />

    public string Chunk
    {
        get { return chunk; }
        set
        {
            if (value == chunk || (value != null && value.Length > 400))
                return;

            chunk = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Chunk");
        }
    }
```

Now if I write something into the TextBox the content of the TextBlock is updated as expected. But if I write something to the Chunk from the background neither the content of the TextBlock nor of the TextBox will be updated. The OnPropertyChanged event is fired but will obviously be ignored.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try to indicate the 2ways? Text="{Binding Path=Chunk, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}

Comment: @Benoît Do you mean the Mode=TwoWay? Yes, didn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your ViewModel. I forget this all the time.

Comment: Yes!! This was the problem. Thank you!